# php - Could not get Laravel $error to appear in blade.php

Tags: php, laravel

Currently working with Laravel v5.4.36. For some reason I wasn't able to get $error to display anything within this block of code:

**login.blade.php:**

```
@if ($errors->has('email'))
    <span class="help-block">
        <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
    </span>
@endif
```

Doing a print_r on $error seems to return an empty array, being:

```
Illuminate\Support\ViewErrorBag Object
(
    [bags:protected] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

From the side of **AuthenticatesUsers.php** I was able to get the array returned when I did the same print_r, thereby suspecting it could be a problem with the session:

```
Array
(
    [email] => Invalid Email ID or Password.
)
```

**AuthenticatesUsers.php:**

```
protected function sendFailedLoginResponse(Request $request)
{
    $errors = [$this->username() => trans('auth.failed')];
    if ($request->expectsJson()) {
        return response()->json($errors, 422);
    }

    return redirect()->back()
        ->withInput($request->only($this->username(), 'remember'))
        ->withErrors($errors);
}
```

However on my **Kernel.php** I already have StartSession and ShareErrorsFromSession under $middleware.

**Kernel.php**

```
protected $middleware = [
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
    \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
];

protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\langMiddleware::class,
    ],

    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
        'bindings',
    ],
];
```

Is there anything else I should be looking out for? Should be something elementary that I am missing out... Cheers.

Comment: are there other signs that sessions are working?  for instance, can you correctly login and maintain that login state?

Comment: Yeap - Logins are working fine. Session files are being created under framework\sessions....